# jQuery after divide number add symbol

Tags: javascript

I have text at the cell and want to:

1. if last number is not equal zero then number / 10 and add symbol "+", so ex. +15.7
2. if last number is equal 0 then number / 10. Result it ex. 15 and add symbol "+" and ".0", so ex. +15.0

   `<td id='testid'>157</td>`

I create javascript and do not how add auxiliary symbols. This solution do not work correctly.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var predpona = '+';
    var pom = $('#testid').text();
    var lastChar = pom.slice(-1);
    var newPom; 
      if (lastChar != '0') {newPom = (pom/10) } else {newPom = (pom/10).prepend(predpona); }
      $('#testid').text(newPom);
  });
</script>
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: Is `pom` always 3 characters long?

Answer (score 1):

If the decimal part is always after the second character here you have an alternative

```
var predpona = '+';
var pom = $('#testid').text();
var index = 2;
var newPom = predpona + [pom.slice(0, index), '.', pom.slice(index)].join('');
```

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes number can be smaller than 10. It protect by if conditions for var index.

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseint()`, it converts the value into integer form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var predpona = '+',
        pom = $('#testid').text(),
        lastChar = pom.slice(-1),
        newPom = parseint(pom) / 10;
    if (lastChar == '0')
        newPom += '.0';
    $('#testid').text('+' + newPom);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **always** want one decimal place and the line preceded with a "+" symbol try this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var predpona = '+';
    var pom = $('#testid').text();
    var lastChar = pom.slice(-1);
    var newPom = predpona + (pom / 10).toFixed(1);

    $('#testid').text(newPom);
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qm3foxe6/4/) to mess around with.